# Jupyter Notebooks MXNet import "RuntimeError: Cannot find the MXNet library."

Tags: python, numpy, pip, jupyter, mxnet

I tried to import MXNet package in a Jupyter notebook and got an error which i could not fix after trying a lot of solutions.

[image]

Bottom of the stack trace looks like this:

[image]

What could be the cause of the issue here? I have Python 3.8 on PATH, MXNet 1.6.0 and Windows 10.

A lot of you would want to clarify if i imported the package in the first place. I did, as you can see. Numpy was imported with no issues, and mxnet did not, even though you can clearly see it present in my Lib->Site Packages.

[image]

Comment: Could you try reinstalling mxnnet? `pip install --force-reinstall mxnet`

Comment: I reinstalled MXNet and it made no difference.